# Building JSF Project with Spring Boot

Tags: jsf-2, spring-boot

I want to build a Spring Boot Project with JSF and Maven.
I tried it with the dependency with the artifact-id spring-boot-starter-web.
The Error Message is, that the JSPFacelet is missing.

Know everyone these Problem and have solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need specify which artifact is the parent of your POM

```
      <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I ve done that, but the spring boot web dependency load or configure (not sure what happend there) a jsp.jar.

Comment: When i try to start the tomcat with my jsf application, the tomcat throw the error message that JSPFacelet is missing, bit i dont need a JSPFacelet.

Comment: are you using a maven project?